# Copying Dynamic Range of Sheets to a Single Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to consolidate several different parts lists on different sheets into one master list.

The problem is that sometimes, for example, the main frame parts or trim parts will have multiple sheets (e.g. Main frame, Main frame (2), Trim, Trim (2), Trim (3), etc.) for different sections.

So I can't hardcode values like I previously thought because the number of sheets vary for each workbook. The first sheet I copy from and the last sheet I copy from are the same, but depending on the workbook, their could be sheets before and are ALWAYS sheets after it that I don't want to include so I can't count back from the last sheet or always start with the first sheet.

I am no VBA expert and it is seemingly robust enough to handle my problem, I just don't know how to specifically go about it.

I've attached the logic to my code that I currently use to concatenate all the sheets into one, but it isn't dynamic enough to work for each case. (Also sorry for the poor style)

Any help or just a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
    On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Master"
Sheets(2).Activate
' Add copy logo once here.

Range("A6").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlUp)(1)
For j = 2 To 13 ' Range of sheets
Sheets(j).Activate
Range("A6").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

' Adjust here to eliminate header but include 2 rows below it
Selection.Offset(5, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 5).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(6)
Next

Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A1:O1").Select
Range("O1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("O10").Select

Range("A1:O4").Select
Range("O4").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: So is this code that you use across different workbooks, but they have a different amount of worksheets?

Comment: Yes. It is only being applied to one workbook at a time to combine sheets in that workbook, but I want it to be able to work on different workbooks with the slight possible variations I mentioned above.

Comment: So do you want it to be able to run for more than 12 worksheets/less than 12 worksheets, or do you want this to skip certain worksheets?

Comment: Yes. more than 12 and possibly less than 12. And I want it to be able to skip worksheets in the beginning or end. The first sheet that it will copy will always be the same name as well  as the last sheet it will copy. But there is a chance that there are different named sheets before it and there are almost always sheets after it that I don't want to include

Comment: I've edited my post with your new block of code, I think I've edited it correctly, however I'm a little thrown off now because of the whole new revamp of code so please excuse any erroneous compile errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will cycle through the sheets until it sees the first sheet, then begin looping through all your sheets until it does the last sheet, to which it will stop running after. Just put the sheet names in there.

```
Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim j as integer
Dim k as integer
ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For k = 1 to ws_count
    If Sheets(k).Name = "FirstSheet" Then
        For j = k to ws_count
            Sheets(j).Activate
            Range("A6").Select
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

            ' Adjust here to eliminate header but include 2 rows below it
            Selection.Offset(5, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 5).Select
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(6)
            If Sheets(j).Name = "LastSheet" Then
                Exit For 
            End If
        Next j
    Exit For
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: looks like it would work to me but am getting an error. Compile error: For control variable already in use. can you not nest for-loops in VBA?

Comment: Oops you can, I was using k twice by accident. Switched in j, try it now-

Comment: My apologies, I think i copied the wrong block of code. I just edited the post to include the accurate block that selects the tables and pastes them to a new sheet. will your solution in its form still work for that code? Again, sorry!! and thank you so much for your replies.

Comment: the code I initially presented ran through each sheet and added two columns. the part that is now posted copies each sheet's list over to a master list.

Comment: So is Sheets(1) still going to remain the master sheet or does that need to be changed now too?

Comment: right after I create it, I think Sheets(1) should remain the master sheet as I am not adding any more sheets

Comment: dwirony, I need your help again!

Comment: @AnthonyRichards What's up Anthony?

Comment: (aside from my item lvl :P)  I have added two columns two my varying amount of worksheets, and would like to add a formula to the top or bottom of each new column (whichever is easiest), and then autofill the rest of the column with that formula as well. I can provide what I have so far as well as an example if it would help.. The trick is that just like there are a varying amount of worksheets, the lists I am adding to vary in size as well

Comment: So we'll have to devise a dynamic solution. Let me get back to you tomorrow, I was busy today with some quarter end work.

Comment: Okay, so what are your formulas, what are your columns, and what is the first cell of each column (where you're putting the formulas?). All you have to do is have the macro place the formula in the cell, then get the `lastrow` of the column and use `.Autofill` the formula the whole way down.

Comment: Formulas are two simple subtraction formulas. Qty remaining and Wt remaining.. So just Qty column minus the Qty ship column and Weight minus Weight shipped column. The "Qty remaining" and "wt remaining columns are always located in Column K and L. the first cell is located in the 9th row. I guess the biggest challenge (and apologies for probably not being clear on this) is that the Qty, Qty ship, Wt, and Wt shipped columns are in varying locations depending on the sheet

Comment: I was thinking I could use case statements for each sheet if finding the Qty, Qty, shipped, Weight, and Wt shipped columns dynamically would be a pain in the butt.

Comment: I can provide screenshots, files ,and how I currently parse through to find certain column headings now for a different macro.

Comment: I know I asked too much lol. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction... good luck with your quarter end work... FOR THE HORDE!